# is_same and variadic template compile-time error invalid conversion

Tags: c++, c++11

So I'm working on a project and I passed in different types of variables to my class to initialize the tuple. Now somewhere in my code I want to check if one of the tuple element, say the element at index 0, is of type int. And if it's of type int, I will change its value. I did that by using is_same and decltype to check if the types are same and if they are the same, I will perform the modifications, as I did in the main below. However, when I try to compile that code, the compiles gives me error saying invalid conversion. But since the types are different, shouldn't this if branch never be reached? Or is there another way to check for type and perform the modification as I want? Thanks

```
template <typename ...args>
class A
{
public:
   A(args&&...params)
   {
      m_tuple = new std::tuple<args...>(params...);
   }
   std::tuple<args...>* m_tuple;
};


int main()
{
  if (std::is_same<int,std::string>::value)
  {
      int i = "12";
  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated note: const char* and std::sting are not the same thing.

Comment: Even if this block code would never be reached *at run-time*, compiler must compile it. Probably you should consider using `if constexpr` to compile some branches of your code in selectively manner - if some condition is true *at compile-time* then compile, otherwise not.

Comment: C++ is not an Interpreted language, So when you compile , the compiler must validate code and create assembly code for that and so on, So compiler doesn't know that the branch will be reached or not!!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a specific index in tuple has a specific type, you can do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;


template <typename ...args>
class A {
public:

    A(args&&...params) {
      m_tuple = new std::tuple<args...>(params...);
    }

    std::tuple<args...>* m_tuple;


    template <std::size_t index, typename c_type>
    constexpr bool holds_type() {
        using type = typename std::tuple_element<
            (index > sizeof...(args) ? 0 : index),
            std::tuple<args...>
        >::type;
        return sizeof...(args) > index && std::is_convertible<c_type, type>::value;
    }
};


int main() {

    A<std::string, int> a("str", 10);
    A<int, std::string> b(10, "str");

    if (a.holds_type<1, int>()) {
        std::cout << "type a<1> is: int" << std::endl;
    }

    if (b.holds_type<0, std::string>()) {
        std::cout << "type b<0> is: std::string" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "type b<0> is not a std::string" << std::endl;
    }


  return 0;
}
```